# Watanabe characterization of a Poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, functional-equations

There is an implication that I am not able to find by myself in my lecture notes.

I consider $X_t$ a cadlag process with values in $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ such that $X_t$ is locally integrable (with respect to $t$) and integrable with respect to $\omega$. We define the function $\phi(s) = \mathbb{E}[X_s]$ and I have the following functional equation for $0<a<b$ and $\lambda$ fixed

$$
\phi(b) = \phi(a) + \lambda(e^{iu}-1)\mathbb{E}[\int_{a}^{b} X_s ds]
$$

This implies the following equality

$$
\phi(t) = \phi(a)e^{\lambda(e^{iu}-1)(t-a)}
$$

for all $t\geq a$. I do not see how to find this implication, I guess there is (maybe) a link with the solution of an ODE when looking at the exponential term ? I would like to have some hint please rather than a full answer please.

Comment: Try applying Fubini's theorem in your functional equation to get an integral equation for $\phi$.

Comment: @Michh Thank you for your comment. Using this hint, we get $\phi(t) = \phi(a) + \lambda(e^{iu}-1)\int_{a}^{t}\phi(s)ds$. Then, differentiating both sides we have $\phi(t)’ = \lambda(e^{iu}-1)\phi(t)$ and taking anti derivatives both sides and using the initial condition I find $\phi(t)=\phi(a)e^{\lambda(e^{iu}-1)t}$ which is not exactly what I should find. However I do not see the mistake in what I did ?

Comment: The initial condition is $\phi(t)=\phi(a)$ when $t=a$ not when $t=0\,.$

Comment: You are right thank you !